# proxmox: NAT 1 public IP of 2 public IPs

Tags: iptables, nat, proxmox

I need some help, because I really stuck, and I don't know why.

I am using proxmox I've got 4 virtual machines. Three of them run well with their own public IP, but I also want to install mailcleaner. Mailcleaner itself seem to run with a class-C-IP only (192.168.1.2). So I have to NAT one IP.

At the moment I can ping and SSH the virtual machine(Mailcleaner) from the Proxmox-Server and also from virtual machine to Proxmox. But it don't seem to NAT right. I can't ping Google, nor can I SSH the virtual machine(Mailcleaner) from my home-computer.

Configurations:

proxmox-server /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp2s0

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual
        address  85.114.141.175
        netmask  255.255.255.255
        dns-nameservers 62.141.32.5 62.141.32.4 62.141.32.3
        dns-search dus2.servdiscount-customer.com
        up ip route add 89.163.247.209/32 dev enp2s0

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  85.114.141.175
        netmask  32
        gateway  85.114.141.1
        bridge-ports enp2s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0


iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address  2001:4ba0:fff6:00a3::0
        netmask  64
        gateway  2001:4ba0:fff6:1:beef::1

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  89.163.247.209
        netmask  32
        gateway  85.114.141.1
        bridge-ports enp2s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0


auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
        address  192.168.1.1
        netmask  24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.0/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.0/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 1022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:22
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 1022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:22
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 1443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:443
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 1443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:443
```

My decisions for this config are:
- the IP of vmbr1 must be reachable from the INet. So, it's also added to the enp2s0 (~eth0). Packets from internet arrive at server for IP 89.163.247.209. The Proxmox-Server takes the Packages and vmbr1 takes over the packets because it is responsible for this IP. Then it should be NAT'ed.

The routing table on Proxmox is looking like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ve26-s1-h3ec6.i 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
mailcleaner.dus 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr2
```

and  iptables -L -t nat shows

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1022 to:192.168.1.2:22
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1443 to:192.168.1.2:443

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
```

On the virtual machiche(MailClient) the network-config looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up modprobe ipv6
pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6
```

I know: the problem is sitting 40 cm in fromt of the PC, but where am I so horribly wrong?

Greetz and thanks in advance

Denise

Comment: "_Mailcleaner itself seem to run with a class-C-IP only (192.168.1.2)_" Seriously? Network classes have been deprecated since 1993 (26 years ago - before the Internet went commercial!). Modern networking does not use network classes.

Comment: I tried everything to use a public IP-Adress on mailcleaner, but every try failed.

Comment: I think you missed my point, which is that there are no such things as network classes anymore. Yes, you can use a Private network address, as you have done, but that doesn't make it a Class C network because you could use other masks, including shorter masks that classful networking would not allow.